# Turbolinks in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am using turbolinks in my project. In index action I have show link when the link is clicked the preloader  loads and nothing happens. I have enabled turbo-links-track :'reload' option to track the changes in the source. Why links are not behave correctly if turbolins enabled. If  I disable the turbolink by data-turbo-links:false it works fine.

At application.html.erb

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'security_managers/application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller], 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

This is in index view

```
 <button class="btn"><%=link_to  image_tag("view.svg"), staff_path(staff), 'data-turbolinks': false %>
 <%= will_paginate @collection, previous_label:"", next_label:"", page_links: false, 'data-turbolinks': false %>
```

Comment: can u share some line of sample, that you have tried???

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the proper links in the application.html.erb, 
In the /application.js  //= require turbolinks,
Also call your functions like that :
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function()

Comment: I have added require turbolinks at application.js. What do you refer by calling the functions? . The get request on clicking on the link reaches the server. But there is no head request made when link is clicked

Comment: please share some code where can see what is the issue thank you Aarthi